# How to add row-span in view-based NSTableView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion, nstableview

I'm trying to get a table layout as shown below working with view-based NSTableViews that have been introduced in Lion.

There were multiple approaches described for cell-based NSTableViews, e.g. [Mimic the artwork column](http://www.noodlesoft.com/blog/2009/10/20/yet-another-way-to-mimic-the-artwork-column-in-cocoa), but these don't really apply for view based table views.

The idea is that the table gets populated by an array of objects, in one (or more) column spanning rows indicating that objects share some data in common. `numberOfRowsInTableView:` returns to total number of items (19 in the case of the attached image).

Has anyone tried something like this?

**Layout**

[image: Groups/sections displayed using spanning rows]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do this by **using two separate NSTableViews that have their NSScrollView's scrolling synchronized**. To learn how to synchronize multiple scroll view's (with the exact subclass code) read [Scroll View Programming Guide for Mac - Synchronizing Scroll Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/SynchroScroll.html)

I have groupTableView that has a single column and shows the views that represent the group. I also have itemTableView that has columns representing the items of the group. I use the same delegate/datasource methods with if-else-statements to check which NSTableView is being used and respond accordingly with the proper # of rows, cell view, etc..  Additionally, I implement the following delegate method to adjust the group table view's row height to be equal the sum of the item row heights of the rows in the group:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row
{
    if (tableView == self.groupTableView) {
        NSUInteger firstRowIndexForGroup = ...;
        NSUInteger lastRowIndexForGroup = ...;
        CGFloat groupHeight = 0.0;
        for (NSUInteger currentRowIndex = firstRowIndexForGroup; currentRowIndex <= lastRowIndexForGroup; currentRowIndex++) {
            groupHeight += [self.itemTableView rectOfRow:lastRowIndexForGroup].size.height;
        }
        return groupHeight - [self.itemTableView intercellSpacing].height;
    } else {
        return self.itemTableView.rowHeight;
    }
}
```

You must also call `-noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:` every time the table view needs a group view because the height changes according to the number of rows in the group.

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    if (tableView == self.groupTableView) {
        GroupRowView *view = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
        // configure view
        [tableView noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:row]];
        return view;
    } else {
        ItemRowView *view = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
        // configure view
        return view;
    }
}
```

I disabled row selection and horizontal and vertical scroll bars on the group table view. I also made the horizontal grid solid for both table views. Finally, I position the group table view directly next to the item table view with no gap in between so it appears as if it's simply another column in a single table view. The result is a flawless implementation that has zero lag between the table views. To the user, it appears as if it's a single table view.

Comment: Oh wow … this is definitely a solution that wouldn't exactly hit my mind first thing! Having worked with synchronised scrolling before I can see how it works. Probably one thing to add is if the group cell gets clicked/selected this would then have to 'forward' the selection to the first row of the item table view.

Comment: You can also split the group table view up to optionally contain two rows per group, this way you can make the top row float above the others, so if you have a large group, your group info floats until the last group item scrolls off screen.

Comment: What did you come up with for keeping the rows of the items table in sync with the group table? How do you keep the items table from sorting its rows so that they don't correspond with the group they're next to?

Comment: @erynofwales I rely on the groups for ordering. Items are never sorted as a whole (the items wouldn't remain grouped). Sorting the groups as a whole, then sorting each group's items is acceptable. When changes are made to the group, both table view's are reloaded. I use a separate data source object that encapsulates access to the data and exposes methods like -indexOfGroup: and -indexOfItem: and -groupAtIndex: and -itemAtIndex: that are used within the table view's data source methods. Internally the data source object uses two arrays (one for groups, one for items) for speed and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use an `NSOutlineView` instead? It's specifically designed to have grouping support.

Comment: But how would you get the group value into a cell with its height being the total height of all child node rows instead of using its very own row?