# How to keep group and item NSTableViews in sync?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I'm working on an app for which I'd like to do something very similar to the problem proposed in this question: [How to add row-span in view-based NSTableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235622/how-to-add-row-span-in-view-based-nstableview)

The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12364544/1174185) intrigues me as a clever solution, but I can't figure out how to keep the two table views in sync with each other. In particular, I don't see any obvious way to make sure that the rows in the item table view show up next to the group the correspond to. The most obvious solutions to me are:

1. Basing the data source of the items table on that of the group table view. So, each object in the group data source has a list of the items that belong to it, then each time the item table view needs a row, iterate through the groups, and count the items in each group until you find the one you need. This sounds *horribly* inefficient.
2. Some clever application of NSSortDescriptors on the items such that they end up sorted so the rows match up. This seems kind of magic to me, like you'd be lucky if you could get it to work deterministically.
3. Keep a pointer to the current group you're processing through and return the next item in the group until you've exhausted the group's items, then move on to the next group. This would depend on the table view asking for rows in sequential order. Seems like this would also be really difficult if there was any concurrency or out-of-order-ness anywhere.

All of these solutions have some pretty obvious flaws. I feel like I'm missing the "trick" here, or maybe just the giant purple elephant standing in front of me. :)

**Edit:** In response to [rdelmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1285133/rdelmar)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616776/how-to-keep-group-and-item-nstableviews-in-sync#comment20413690_14616776), I'll add a few clarifications. For my particular case, the number of items in a group is variable — some groups could have two, others ten. The solution I'd like to find shouldn't depend on there being a fixed number of items in a group.

In terms of selection behavior, it's probably not necessary that each item in a group be selectable, but they do need to be editable. Groups will probably be edited as a whole, i.e. the user will say "I want to edit group A", which will trigger the ability to edit any field in the group or the items that belong to it. It's probably possible to use labels instead of a table view, but it seems like that would involve duplicating a lot of work the table view would give you for free (arranging views in a grid, etc).

The very first solution I came up with for this actually involved embedding a table view for the items inside each row of the group table view. So, the top-level table view would consist only of groups, then each group would have its own embedded table for displaying the items it has. I eventually gave up on that solution in hopes of finding one that involved a shorter view tree.

Comment: It would be helpful to know a little more about what you're trying to do. Are the items (as shown in your link) dynamically changing, or does each group have a set number of items (but could be different between groups)? What kind of selection behavior do you need? Do those rows of items need to be rows of a table view, or could each group be one row, with the items in labels or maybe a text view?

Comment: Hi @rdelmar, I updated the post with the answers to your questions. (Don't know if you get notifications of my edits as a commenter.) Thanks for your thoughts. :)

Comment: I have a demo project that uses an NSForm to hold the items, and I add or subtract rows from it depending on the number of items in a particular group. I can send it to you, if you would like to look at this approach. My email is rdelmar@comcast.net